# JSON int array to DataContract array

Tags: c#, json, wpf, windows-phone-8, datacontract

im having trouble translating a json response from google's apis to DataContract classes. Specifically when trying to translate an int array from JSON to an int array in the DataContract.

Heres what I have done so far.

Heres the JSON response.

```
{
 "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
 "columnHeaders": [
  {
   "name": "views",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "likes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
   "name": "dislikes",
   "columnType": "METRIC",
   "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   2162435,
   871,
   907
  ]
 ]
}
```

And heres my Data Contract classes

```
[DataContract]
public class AnalyticsData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "kind")]
    public string Kind { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "columnHeaders")]
    public ColumnRows[] ColumnHeaders { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "rows")]
    public int[][] rows { get; set; }  //<--------

}

[DataContract]
public class ColumnRows
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "columnType")]
    public string ColumnType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dataType")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am having is translating the 'rows' element from the JSON doc into DataContract variables, as as shown in the AnalyticsData class in the int array 'rows'.

The error I get when debugging is

*System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type StudioWP8.AnalyticsData. Input string was not in a correct format. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.*

Comment: you cannot use List<List<int>> instead of int[][]?

Comment: Which serialization library are you using?

Comment: Using `DataContractJsonSerializer` this works for me -- I don't get the exception.  What serializer?  What is the full traceback?  Are these the actual classes & JSON that reproduce the bug, or are they simplifications?

Comment: @dbc the serialization class i am using is System.Runtime.Serialization. Im calling the serilization by `var analyticsData = await request.GetValueFromRequest<AnalyticsData>();

                Debug.WriteLine(analyticsData.Rows[0][1]);`

Comment: `System.Runtime.Serialization` is a [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not a serializer.  Can you edit your question to include the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: @dbc im using DataContractJsonSerializer as my json serializer, as for the full traceback : http://notepad.cc/flibbami71 (since the full exception goes over the char limit)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on the destop by reading the JSON you provided in from an inline string.  Perhaps it's an encoding issue, or something specific to WP8.  Incidentally, while all your `dataType`'s are of value `INTEGER`, the [API says](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/) says "The type of the data in the column (STRING, INTEGER, FLOAT, etc.)".  If you JSON rows were not integers, you would see this exception.

Comment: Also, [this Java code sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/java) suggests you should use `long` not `int`: `if ("INTEGER".equals(header.getUnknownKeys().get("dataType"))) {
   long l = ((BigDecimal) column).longValue();`

Comment: @dbc i took your advice and used String instead of Int and it worked! I also changed the 2d arrays to a list instead for easy looping`public List<List<string>> Rows { get; set; }` Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use jsonconvert and it will be ok

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void test()
    {
        string json =
            "{ \"kind\": \"youtubeAnalytics#resultTable\", \"columnHeaders\": [  {   \"name\":\"views\",   \"columnType\": \"METRIC\",   \"dataType\": \"INTEGER\"  },  {   \"name\": \"likes\",   \"columnType\": \"METRIC\",   \"dataType\": \"INTEGER\" },  {   \"name\": \"dislikes\",   \"columnType\": \"METRIC\",   \"dataType\":\"INTEGER\"  } ], \"rows\": [  [   2162435,   871,907  ] ]}";

        AnalyticsData d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnalyticsData>(json);

    }
```